# Running into issue need db server type using php

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

I am here again I ran into an interesting issue with a php page I have been working with, come to find out that At home I am using MySQL and at school where I am also working on this project I am using MariaDB. This issue comes with the SQL query and creating the tables, MariaDB when using timestamps requires a default value otherwise it auto adds an ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP which is not what I want to do, I have the table set up with a user joined on timestamp, which is set when a new user is created. It works just fine so long as you run it on a mysql server. But when I was working on it the other day found that the development database at school is MariaDB 10.x so the user joined date was always being updated... Looked into the MariaDB KB and it stated that a default was required when the table was created Otherwise the ON UPDATE would be added... So I came up with the following (bear with me I am aware that this probably looks terrible, which is why I am looking to just grab the type...

```
  function create_tables(){
// This call will intregrate to the install, this will get the version numbers of the sql server, and deturmine what the server is running and then will
//create the tabels for the correct server.
global $db;
$query = "SELECT Version() as 'dbV' ";
$stmnt = $db -> prepare($query);
$stmnt -> execute();
$result = $stmnt -> get_result();
$results = $result -> fetch_assoc();
$version = $results['dbV'];
// For MYSQL 5.6 or newer will be required
// For MariaDB 5.5, and all 10.x will be supported
$shortVersion = str_replace('.','',$version);
//version division ... Yay
if (((int)$shortVersion / 10000) >=1 ) {
  echo var_dump('MariaDB version: ' . $version );
  return create_tables_MariaDB();
}elseif (((int)$shortVersion / 5700) >=1 && ((int)$shortVersion - 5599) >=1) {
  echo var_dump('MySQL version: ' . $version );
  return create_tables_MySQL();
}elseif (((int)$shortVersion - 5599) < 1) {
  echo var_dump('MariaDB version: ' . $version );
  return create_tables_MariaDB();
}else{
  echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>You will need to use one of the following DB servers to use this site: MySQL 5.6.X or 5.7.X, MariaDB 5.5.X or 10.X.X. PLease install or update your database server and try again.</div>";
  exit();
}
}
```

The thing is that MySQL and MariaDB both have active releases of 5.5.X so I had to choose... so My Main question is::

Is there a cleaner way to grab the database server type? It would be so much cleaner to just check Mysql, or MariaDB and then do the calls to the specific functions to create the tables...

Any advise would be very helpful,

Jesse Fender

This is my Newly edited and much neater code, Thanks to @Demi for his help...

```
  function create_tables(){
// This call will intregrate to the install, this will get the version numbers of the sql server, and deturmine what the server is running and then will
//create the tabels for the correct server.
global $db;
$query = "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'";
$stmnt = $db -> prepare($query);
$stmnt -> execute();
$result = $stmnt -> get_result();
while ($results = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
    $version[] = $results;
}

// echo var_dump($version );
$ver_name = $version[5]['Value'];
//echo var_dump(substr($ver_name,0,5));
if (substr($ver_name,0,5)==="MySQL") {
  return create_tables_MySQL();
}elseif (substr($ver_name,0,5)==="Maria") {
  return create_tables_MariaDB();
}else{
  echo "<p class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid Database Connection. Please only use MySQL or MariaDB servers.</p>";
}
}
```

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";

Comment: @Dimi Did you -1 me for asking an honest question? ...

Comment: Nah.The whole downvote thing on questions makes no sense to me. Answers maybe, but not questions. And according to my vote history I have literally never down-voted anything.

Comment: This works exactly like a select.

Comment: never mind, I was being stupid... lol Thanks man lots of help.

Comment: The handling of "default" for datatype `TIMESTAMP` has changed a time or two -- check the details for _your_ version.

Comment: Thats handled elsewhere... This was to determine the database that was being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
```

Output on MariaDB

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                       |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.34-79.1                 |
| protocol_version        | 10                          |
| slave_type_conversions  |                             |
| version                 | 10.1.21-MariaDB             |
| version_comment         | MariaDB Server              |
| version_compile_machine | i686                        |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                       |
| version_malloc_library  | system                      |
| version_ssl_library     | OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017 |
| wsrep_patch_version     | wsrep_25.16                 |
+-------------------------+-----------------------------+
10 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

output on MySQL

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.35                       |
| protocol_version        | 10                           |
| slave_type_conversions  |                              |
| version                 | 5.6.35                       |
| version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                        |
+-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Do keep in mind that there are many different versions and flavors of MySQL

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value                                            |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.20-68.0                                      |
| protocol_version        | 10                                               |
| slave_type_conversions  |                                                  |
| version                 | 5.6.20-68.0-log                                  |
| version_comment         | Percona Server (GPL), Release 68.0, Revision 656 |
| version_compile_machine | x86_64                                           |
| version_compile_os      | Linux                                            |
+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```